# Ergodicity breaking in supercooled liquids

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ergodicity

What is a [ergodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory) system? What is Onset temperature of [ergodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity) breaking in super cooled liquids when we go towards lower temperature?